# Glob searching directories also returns files

Tags: c++, posix, glob, glibc

Why does does using the `glob` function with the path `/home/user/*/` return both directories **and** files. I expect that since the path ends in `/`, only directories should be returned, but it is also returning files.

I am running the following code:

```
vector<string> glob(const std::string& path)
{
    glob_t glob_result;
    glob(path.c_str(),GLOB_TILDE,NULL,&glob_result);
    vector<string> ret;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<glob_result.gl_pathc;++i){
        ret.push_back(string(glob_result.gl_pathv[i]));
    }
    globfree(&glob_result);
    return ret;
}
```

The input for the function is `/home/user/*/` and the output is `/home/user/a.txt`, `/home/user/b.txt` and `/home/user/nested_folder`

Why is returning both files and directories instead of only directories.

Comment: Where does it say it only searches for directories? :)

Comment: " I would expected that only directories will be found" - why do you expect that?

Comment: [`GLOB_ONLYDIR`!](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html)

Comment: @Caramiriel @Neil POSIX is pretty clear that the `/` in the pattern has to match a directory (*Any component, except the last, that does not contain a pattern character shall require search permission*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old glibc bug which was fixed in glibc 2.19:

- [glob() gives inconsistent results with trailing "/"](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10278) (bug report)
- [When glob pattern contains a trailing slash match only directories](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=a471e96a5352a5f0bde6d32dd36d33524811a2b1) (commit)

Comment: still [not fixed](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25659)